# CSS / HTML / PHP Displaying List of Alternating Arrays (Google Chrome Extension)

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a google chrome extension in which several different arrays (Name, Age, Country etc.) are passed to the popup.html and they are displayed using HTML / CSS / PHP something similar to:

> John Doe                 28 
>   America 
>   
>   Paul Smith               58 
>   Japan 
>   
>   Robert Green           39 
>   Germany

I'm able to pass each array to popup.html except only the last array passed is displayed - I haven't been able to find a way to display each entry of alternating arrays.

At this point I'm confused as to what my approach should be. Should I be using lists, or changing the way the arrays are passed to the HTML file or is there a simple way to display alternating arrays?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Note:

> Name = ['John Doe', 'Paul Smith', 'Robert Green'] 
>   Age = [28, 58, 39] 
>   Country = ['America', 'Japan', 'Germany']

EDIT - UPDATED WITH SAMPLE CODE

('msg' is a single array for demonstration purposes passed into popup.js from background.js)

popup.js:

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "Sample Communication"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        document.getElementById('status').textContent = msg;
});
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body { 
                min-width       : 400px;
                min-height      : 300px;
                text-align      : right;
                background-color: #D0D0D0; }
           #status { 
                font-size       : 10px;
                color           : #0000CC;
                text-align      : left;
                font-family     : "Times New Roman", Times, serif; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Running this simply displays the array in a comma-separated paragraph. From more research it seems that using PHP might be the easiest way to implement a table; however, I'm still unsure whether it is possible to pass the array into the table.

Comment: How are you passing your arrays to popup.html?  The best may be to pass all three at once: `{Name:[...],Age:[...],Country:[...]}`.

Comment: This is pretty specific to your implementation.  Try sharing the code relevant to this.

Comment: So far I've just been trying to pass all three separately, but I will definitely change that if there's a way to display values from each array. I'm new(ish) to HTML and CSS so I'm unsure about what is capable within these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply overwriting your display each time you receive a new piece of data:

```
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  // This wipes the old value:
  document.getElementById('status').textContent = msg;
});
```

You'll need to either append data, or better yet pass all of the data at once, format it properly, and then output it to the page.

---

It's really hard to be more detailed with the answer since: 1) you don't seem to know very well what you're doing, 2) there are no precise specifications in the question.

You should practice a bit more on your own and look up a few tutorials, otherwise helping you won't really be helpful to you, or to others. Then, if you still have questions (probably not extension-specific), split them into chunks and post here. [This guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I guess I was just finding it difficult to be specific in my question because I am unsure of what is possible to achieve with CSS / HTML / PHP. How would you go about taking all the data (either passed as one array or multiple) and formatting it as outlined in the question? I am yet to find an example I can adapt or that addresses this unique problem. Thanks!