# Format array for display from HTML file

Tags: html, css, arrays, google-chrome-extension, format

I'm currently working on a Google Chrome extension which passes an array to a HTML file for the results to be displayed. My array looks something like this:

```
var Array = ['Jason Smith', 81, 'Japan', 'Paul Prince', 19, 'USA', 'Wesley JJ', 60, 'France']
```

And I'm trying to display this from the HTML file to look something like:

> Jason Smith 
>   81                     Japan 
>   
>   Paul Prince 
>   19                     USA 
>   
>   Wesley JJ 
>   60                     France

Here is my popup.html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body { 
                min-width       : 400px;
                min-height      : 300px;
                text-align      : right;
                background-color: #D0D0D0; }
            #status { 
                font-size       : 10px;
                color           : #0000CC;
                text-align      : left;
                font-family     : "Times New Roman", Times, serif; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "Sample Communication"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        document.getElementById('status').textContent = msg;
});
```

Note: "status" is the array passed from background.js to popup.js then to popup.html (background.js simply creates the array).

This should, for the most part, just be a formatting issue (unless there's something else I'm missing) so any help or insight into a method for formatting this array would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Okay so I've tried a few things - as it stands I can pass the array to simply display like this using Array.join(" "):

> Jason Smith 81 Japan Paul Prince 19 USA Wesley JJ 60 France

And I've tried entering some break tags (br) into the array, as well as \n but that doesn't seem to split them up into separate lines. I've also attempted to add in additional spaces but that seems to be a clunky approach to the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS / HTML / PHP Displaying List of Alternating Arrays (Google Chrome Extension)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015662/css-html-php-displaying-list-of-alternating-arrays-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: This question relates purely to formatting of the array to display as outlined in the question.

Comment: Can you provide the **js** codes?

Comment: yeah, as @AlbertoI.N.J. said, could you provide us with what you have so far in popup.js?

Comment: Thanks guys! Just added some code

Answer (score 0):

You've got some data, and you're trying to lay it out in a table. The best element to use for that is the `<table>` element!

Something like this will generate a table as you want:

```
var a = ['Jason Smith', 81, 'Japan', 'Paul Prince', 19, 'USA', 'Wesley JJ', 60, 'France'];
var str = "<table>"
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i+=3) {
    str += "<tr><td colspan=\"2\">" + a[i] + "</td></tr>";
    str += "<tr><td>" + a[i+1] + "</td><td>" + a[i+2] + "</td></tr>";
}
str += "</table>";
```

Note that storing all your data in an array makes this solution a little fragile. For example, you'll have problems if the length of your array is not an exact multiple of three. If you've got control over the data source, something using objects would be tidier:

```
var a = [{
    name: 'Jason Smith',
    age: 81,
    country: 'Japan'
},{
    name: 'Paul Prince',
    age: 19,
    country: 'USA'
},{
    name: 'Wesley JJ',
    age: 60,
    country: 'France'
}];
```

Then your loop becomes less fragile and slightly easier to read:

```
var str = "<table>"
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    str += "<tr><td colspan=\"2\">" + a[i].name + "</td></tr>";
    str += "<tr><td>" + a[i].age + "</td><td>" + a[i].country + "</td></tr>";
}
str += "</table>";
```

Comment: NB This method of constructing strings might not be the most efficient, but it is easy.